# How to transpose specific columns in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, pivot, transpose

I have a following PySpark dataframe:

```
year    week    date    time          value
2020    1     20201203  2:00 - 2:15    23.9
2020    1     20201203  2:15 - 2:30    45.87
2020    1     20201203  2:30 - 2:45    87.76
2020    1     20201203  2:45 - 3:00    12.87
```

I want to transpose the time and value column. The desired output should be:

```
 year   week    date    2:00 - 2:15     2:15 - 2:30     2:30 - 2:45    2:45 - 3:00
 2020   1     20201203    23.9             45.87           87.76          12.87
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` and `pivot`.

```
df = df.groupby('year', 'week', 'date').pivot('time').max('value')
```

Comment: why aggregation is max? we dont have multiple values in 'value' column for corresponding 'time' column. Will first() will not serve the purpose?

Comment: Data is huge. pivot is taking ages to run. Any other efficient approach is required.

Comment: `max`, `min` or `first` would return same because there is only 1 value. you can pick your favorite. but for the `first`, you need `.agg(F.first('value'))`.

Comment: For efficiency, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69191203/most-efficient-way-of-pivoting-huge-dataframes-pyspark.  
or look up "pyspark efficient pivot" in stackoverflow. You'll see a couple of similar questions.